# What is the key to enable the display of the shopper's name in Adyen's dropin for stored cards with ReactJs?

Tags: adyen

Used 'dropin' for showing stored cards. The UI rendered from Adyen dropin component doesn't show the shopper's name.
Is there any key which enables showing the shopper/holder's name in stored cards' container?

Web dropin used with ReactJs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `drop-in` does not provide this built-in configuration option to display the card holder's name directly within the Drop-in component.

You could however get hold of this information making a call to `/paymentMethods`, passing additionally the `shopperReference` and customise the checkout page.

```
fetch('/paymentMethods', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    merchantAccount: 'your_merchant_account',
    shopperReference: 'the_shopper_reference'
  })
})
```